# How to sketch the set S:=$[-0.5,0.5] \times [-2, 2]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

In my Linear Algebra assignment, I should sketch the set S:=$[-0.5,0.5]\times[-2, 2]$ - the cartesian product of the intervals $[-0.5,0.5]$ and $[-2, 2]$. I read a question with a similar exercise here but how it is solved makes no sense for me. What would I have to do if someone ask me "sketch a set" with respect to Linear Algebra? I have to sketch different sets but since I have no clue what to do, I ask this question here. I hope you do not mind it.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Draw $x$ and $y$ axes.  Mark $x=\pm0.5$ on the $x$-axis and $y=\pm2$ on the $y$-axis.  $S$ will be a rectangle.  Do you know how to graph a point such as $(0.5,2)$ on the $xy$-plane?

Comment: Thank you and is that all I have to do? It is funny how they do not tell us what they mean by sketching and just assume that we know what to do...

Comment: Yes, I know that, I think. I am really confused right now about what to do.... Could you use my example or, if you want, choose any example of your choice and sketch the set so that I know what to do?

Comment: Are you familiar with this notation?
$$
S=[-0.5,0.5]\times[-2,2]=\{(x,y):x\in[-0.5,05],y\in[-2,2]\}
$$

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the notation.

Comment: Then simply shade the region where such $(x,y)$ points exist, to "sketch" the $S$. That is, $x$ is at least $-0.5$ but at most $0.5$ and $y$ is at least $-2$ and at most $2$.

Comment: This question doesn't involve much [tag:linear-algebra]

Comment: I was confused too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this picture, the set $S$ is the rectangle where the blue strip and the red strip overlap:

[image]

Comment: So, that would be the fully correct answer if someone asked to sketch a set, in this case the set S?

Comment: if you sketch the purple rectangular region (overlap of blue and red strips), I think that should be fully correct

Comment: Last question to be absolute sure. Would this picture be the correct solution: https://ibb.co/6tQjDBY ? Sorry for all these questions..

Comment: that picture shows the intervals along the $x$- and $y$-axes (not to scale), but doesn't show the rectangular region included in the product shaded in

Comment: Hm.. I thought I should sketch the graph such that all pairs are included in the graph but not more? I give it up but thank you for trying to explain it to me!

Comment: But you've only sketched the lines on the $x$ and $y$ axes.  You haven't sketched any of the points not on the axis.  Note:  If $-0.5 \le x \le 0.5$ and $-2 \le y \le 2$ then the point $(x,y)$ *will* need to be in your sketch.  So you have color in $(0.2, 1.3)$ and $(-0.03, 0.73)$ etc.  You have to color in all the points int the rectangle that J.W. described.  You showed the axes that define the rectangle... but you didn't actually show the rectangle *itself*

Comment: Ah! I understood it know! Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

$[-0.5, 0.5]\times [-2,2] =$

$\{(a,b)| -0.5\le a \le 0.5$ and $-2\le b \le 2\}$

So this is all the points where the $x$ values are between $-0.5$ and $0.5$ inclusively, and the $y$ values are between $-2$ and $2$ inclusively.

How would you describe such a shop and how would you sketch it on graph paper?

> It's a rectangle.... The bottom edge is the line for $x=-0.5$ to $x=-0.5$ at $y=-2$.  The top edge is  the line for $x=-0.5$ to $x=-0.5$ at $y=2$.  The left edge is the line for $y=-2$ to $2$ at $x =-0.5$ and the right edge is the line for $y=-2$ to $2$ at $x =0.5$.  The sketch contains all the points inside and on the edges of the rectangle

Image (DO NOT LOOK AT THIS UNTIL YOU'VE THOUGHT LONG AND HARD ON THE ABOVE):

> [image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: That image doesn't actually show the points. It shows two line that cut right through the set but not that points within the set. Your graph is the sketch of $\{(x,y)| x = 0$ and $-2\le y\le2$ OR $y=0$ and $-0.5\le x \le 0.5\}$.  It does not include any $(x,y)$ where neither $x$ nor $y$ equal $0$.  You need to draw *ALL* $(x,y)$ were $x$ can be anywhere between $-0.5$ and $0.5$ (an not nescessarily $0$) and $y$ can be anywhere between $-2$ and $2$ and *neither* one of them have to be $0$. In other words you need to sketch $(0.3, 1)$ and $(-0.13, 1.089)$.  Your sketch is white at those points.